# Best way to wait for TcpClient data to become available?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

```
while (TcpClient.Client.Available == 0)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Absolutely! Just call `Read(...)` on the stream. That will block until data is available. Unless you really *have* to use the `TcpClient` directly, I'd normally do as much as possible on the stream. If you want to use the socket, just call `Receive(byte[])` which will block until data is available (or the socket is closed).

Now if you don't want to block, you can use `Stream.BeginRead` or `Socket.BeginReceive` to work asynchronously. (Or `ReadAsync` as of .NET 4.5.)

I personally find `Available` to be pretty much useless (on both streams and sockets) and looping round with a sleep is definitely inefficient - you don't want to have to context switch the thread when data hasn't come in, and you don't want to have to wait for the sleep to finish when data *has* come in.

Comment: @Jader: Only if it's passing text from the other end *and* it will close the socket when it's finished sending. Not good for HTTP KeepAlive connections, for example.

Comment: @tig: If `ReadLine` returns null, that means the stream has been closed and there are no more lines available. It really sounds like you should look at what's happening at the network level, e.g. with Wireshark.

Comment: I think they wanted rather one of `Socket.Poll()` or `Socket.Select()`, and since TcpClient haven't the functions, it ideally shouldn't be used. The blocking Read aren't great idea since it doesn't allow to point a time span to wait for a data.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: You can always set `TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout` if you want... won't that do what you're talking about?

Comment: @JonSkeet ah, dat side effects ☺

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Not sure what you mean, but if it does what's required, I think it's a rather simpler solution than using a lower-level API. (Heck, we don't even know whether the OP *wants* a timeout...)

Comment: Just to add to the answer, there's also ReadAsync available since .NET ..... 4.5?

Comment: @Pluc: Added that in. I'm not going to go into all the details of awaiting though :)

Comment: For my case, I'm trying to capture a message with an unspecified length and start/end character that it sent at either 1s in .1s intervals. If I'm trying to capture just a single message in its entirety, and then send that to be parsed, I don't see how I'd do that without `Available`. So maybe it's not completely useless in my case. @JonSkeet

Comment: @Corylulu: You'd keep a buffer, and read as much as you could on each call. Then you'd spot when you've got a whole message, and process that - but retaining anything else that's still in the buffer. Even if the messages are being sent at .1s intervals, you shouldn't assume that what's available to read will never cross a message boundary.